# Facebook fetching wrong final Url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

Facebook is fetching different final url when run through linter

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fbearddesign.co%2Fexperiments%2F1984%2F

It is not taking the sub-directory path of the url as final url resulting in 403 response.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing og:url meta tag, instead of this:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://bearddesign.co/experiments/1984/index.html" />
```

Put this

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://bearddesign.co/experiments/1984/index.php" />
```

or this

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://bearddesign.co/experiments/1984/" />
```